# Rails with Neo4jrb still uses sqlite3 for testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neo4jrb

I have set up my rails app to use Neo4j using [Neo4jRB](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j) which fine both in production and development. In testing however I get the error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table:`for each test, so it seems as though it still wants to use SQLite3.

I have set up my *config/neo4j.yml* so that it points to a running test database, however *database.yml* still points to SQLite3 and if I make changes to that then the error changes, so I'm guessing it has to do with that, but the `neo4jrb` documentation doesn't mention that you need to change *database.yml*.

Here's the test section of my *neo4j.yml*:

`test:
  type: http
  url: http://localhost:7575`

*database.yml* is just the standard Rails generated file:

`default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch(RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3`

Changing the adapter to for instance `neo4jrb` in *database.yml* removes the SQLite exceptions and gives me an adapter not found exception instead.

Comment: What are the changes you have made to `config/neo4j.yml`? What are the changes you have attempted to make to `database.yml`, and what errors occur when you try that?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error, it is stemming from ActiveRecord not Neo4jrb:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table:
```

I'm assuming you have both Neo4jrb and ActiveRecord installed (which is allowed). When you are running your tests, ActiveRecord is not configured properly. If you don't want ActiveRecord installed, you should uninstall it. EIther way, this sounds like an ActiveRecord configuration problem, not a Neo4jrb configuration problem.